# This is my user controller. How to test this code in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How to write test case in this user log in. i am newbie in rails testing
i am using Rspec gem. i need any tutorial for rails test.

```
if params.key?(:mobile) && params.key?(:password)
 user = User.find_by(mobile: params[:mobile], is_active: 1)
                          if user.nil?
                            output = { status: '06', message: 'Invalid user.' }.to_json
                          elsif user.authenticate(params[:password])

                            auth_token = JsonWebToken.encode(id: user.id,
                                                             user_type: user.user_type)
                            object = { id: user.id, user_type: user.user_type,
                                       name: user.name }
                            output = { status: '10', message: 'Successful.',
                                       auth_token: auth_token, user: object}.to_json
                          else
                            output = { status: '06', message: 'Incorrect password.' }.to_json                         
 end
                        else
                          output = { status: '01', message: 'Invalid parameters.' }.to_json
                        end
                        render json: output, status: :ok
```

Comment: You can use RSpec for to write your tests. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to see as an answer? Should we write the tests for you? Or find links to rspec tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rspec gem for writing test cases then you can use [Tutorial point rspec](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/rspec/index.htm) Turorials. It will give good start and let you learn how test works in Ruby on Rails. You can also try some e-books for in depth knoweldge.